# How to clusterize a set of lists consisting of numbers?

Tags: clustering

I have a set of lists (electrical current vs. time dependencies for different samples in electrochemical experiments) and I would like to clustering this data (one current curve with another) to find the proximity of some curves and others. How could I do this?
[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16YDpEucnphXPqD82R1hC-7R2FZQbVXDl/view?usp=share_link) you can find *.csv table with data (each current time dependence) in every row.
I'm newly in clustering and other ML stuff. I know that I have to set the distance function, but as far as I understand in the `FindClusters[]` function, you can select some options.

There is no time in the table, because I decided to reduce the amount of data. I note that each step is 0.105 s.

With best wishes!

A plot of all of the data follows with each color representing one of the 27 sets of samples over time (from 0 to almost 600 seconds).

```
data = Import["cu_all.csv"];
time = 0.105 Range[0, Dimensions[data][[2]] - 1];
data = Transpose[{time, #}] & /@ data;
ListPlot[data]
```

[image: Plot of data]

Comment: What makes you think there are "clusters" rather than a continuum of differences?  This is not intended as a criticism.  I don't know the subject matter and from a plot of all of the data it seems that all samples differ from an "average" shape.  Also, sample 26 (row 26) seems to flatten out around the 4,000th observation.  None of the other samples do that.

Comment: JimB makes a good observation. What to you mean by clustering one curve with another? What's the method for comparison? Maybe use correlation, covariance, etc. to compare pairs of samples, and then collecting pairs with similar statistics.

Comment: I added a plot of the data which I hope will assist others in giving advice about the request.  If that is not appropriate, I'll happily remove that edit.

Comment: Dear Jim. thank you very much, yuo`re a very kind person!

Comment: About sample 26 -- i think that my experiment had going wrong.

Comment: I will try to calculate correlation/covariance and will update my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a method to compare each pair of samples using a statistical measure. We'll use `Covariance`. I put the first 5 of the `cu_all` samples in `data` to keep the outputs small. First, we need a list of pairs of the samples (for 27 samples, there are 351 pairs). With few adjustments, this method will work for the entire set of `cu_all` samples.

```
samplePairs = Subsets[Range[Length[data]], {2}]
(* {{1,2},{1,3},{1,4},{1,5},{2,3},{2,4},{2,5},{3,4},{3,5},{4,5}} *)
```

First, let's find covariances in `covar` for each pair of samples. Next we collect (using `GroupBy`) the sample pairs that have similar covariances. The number `100000` is a heuristic (a guess) based on the samples, and it's chosen to give a useful number of groups.

Each of the results below show the covariance of a pair of samples. For example, `{{1, 2}, 0.0000346729}` shows the covariance `0.0000346729` for samples `1` and `2`.

I need to explain that the code, `100000 Floor[Last[#], 1/100000`, makes an integer that `GroupBy` uses to collect covariances. Change the code to change the number of groups. I used a histogram of the covariances to decide how many groups would work.

```
covar = {#, Covariance[Sequence@@data[[#, All]]]} &/@ samplePairs;
Sort@Normal[groups = GroupBy[covar, 100000 Floor[Last[#], 1/100000]&]]//Column
```

> ```
> 2 -> {{{2,4},0.0000241429}},
> 3 -> {{{1,2},0.0000346729},{{1,4},0.0000333314},{{2,3},0.0000329338},
>       {{2,5},0.0000352122},{{3,4},0.0000312449},{{4,5},0.0000334002}},
> 4 -> {{{1,3},0.0000455905},{{1,5},0.000048605},{{3,5},0.0000463339}}
> ```

Let's look at the 6 sample pairs in `groups[3]` which are `1,2`, `1,4`, `2,3`, `2,5`, `3,4`, and `4,5`.

```
groupedSamples = groups[3][[All, 1]];
GraphicsGrid[Partition[ListPlot[data[[#, All]], 
    PlotLabel -> ToString[#],
    Joined -> True,PlotRange -> All] &/@ groupedSamples,
  UpTo[3]], ImageSize -> 800];
```

[image: six pairs of samples with similar covariance]

Using `Covariance` or `Correlation` is a starting point to make some clusters from paired samples.

Comment: Thank you very much, dear creidhne!